# Rails and jQuery going forward

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

With jQuery being so much more popular and active than prototype. What is the state of the rails community? Are there plans to migrate from prototype and script.aculo.us to jQuery and jQuery.ui (ie integrating jQuery, jQuery.ui and jQuery-ujs into the baseline rails gem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DHH [tweeted on 3/10/2011](http://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/45923430608023552) that jquery will be the default javascript framework starting in version 3.1

> Rails 3.1 will ship with jQuery as the
>   default JavaScript library. Prototype
>   helpers/RJS are going into a gem.

Much like you can use MooTools, Prototype will become something that you can use, but by default it will use jQuery.

Comment: Beat me to it :p  Anyone know if there's any more than that tweet on the subject?  Like a blog post or something?  I'd like to hear more comments from the rails dev about their reasoning.

Comment: what about jquery with rjs support?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is made to be javascript framework agnostic.You can use whatever framework you prefer, gems are here to set it up for you.

Nowadays, prototype is just used as default.

Comment: that's not totally true, is it? I'm pretty new to rails, but even just the rjs helpers are all translated to prototype code.

Comment: that's right, but these helpers are not that useful, I use jQuery and use the kind of syntax you can find here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/136-jquery